# What's the meaning of "to connect the living dots" in the following context?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

> You’re probably wondering why I’ve sent you this letter. Since my
> father died, I’ve made myself write something every day. I want to
> make things, not just study them. Ideally, I write a poem, but on the
> hard days I write correspondence. And today I wrote to you, **to
> connect the living dots** between me, my mother, my father, and
> yourself.

I know that "to connect the dots" means "to find or show the relationships between different things," but I wonder what it means in this context, especially given that we have the word "living" before "dots".

Comment: Why are you puzzled? The text you quote explains it.

Comment: @Xanne - Why connect the "living" dots?!

Comment: @TBY90 It's metaphorical, the writer is comparing the people mentioned to dots on a piece of paper and saying that they are trying to map out, and possibly heal and strengthen the relationships between them. "Living" is used to emphasise that the people are flesh, blood and emotions, not just marks on a page.

Comment: Some people would think that 'connect the dots' was sufficient (it's usually used as a metaphor) and that adding 'living' clouds rather than clarifies.

Comment: Beware of phishing emails. (And people who connect living dots)